# b:commandButton inside dataTable won't fire action method

Tags: jsf-2, wildfly-8, bootsfaces

I just started using BootsFaces because of client's demand, so bear with me.

Here's my xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">

    <b:dataTable id="dtEmpresas" value="#{recController.empresas}" var="e" searching="false" striped="true"
            styleClass="tabela" customLangUrl="../resources/js/lang-pt-br.json" paginated="false" pageLength="6" >

        <b:dataTableColumn header-style-class="hidden" styleClass="col-md-4">
            <b:selectOneMenu id="congenere" value="#{e.congenere.id}"> 
            <!-- required="true" requiredMessage="Congenere é obrigatório"> -->
                <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="[Selecione...]"
                    itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{recController.congeneres}" var="c" 
                    itemLabel="#{c.nome}" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
            </b:selectOneMenu>
        </b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn styleClass="col-md-4" header-style-class="hidden">
            <b:inputText id="nomeEmpresa" value="#{e.nomeEmpresa}" size="50" disabled="#{!e.ehOutros()}" />
        </b:dataTableColumn>
        <b:dataTableColumn styleClass="col-md-4" header-style-class="hidden">
            <b:row>
                <b:column styleClass="col-md-10">
                    <b:inputText value="#{e.cnpj}" size="50" required="false"
                        validatorMessage="CNPJ invalido 21" placeholder="CNPJ Recolhimento">
                        <f:validator validatorId="cnpjValidador" />
                    </b:inputText>
                </b:column>
                <ui:debug hotkey="j" />
                <b:commandButton value=" - " action="#{recController.removeItem(e)}" update="dtEmpresas" />
                <b:commandButton id="btAdd" value=" + " action="#{recController.addItem()}"
                    update="dtEmpresas" process="dtEmpresas" />
            </b:row>
        </b:dataTableColumn>

    </b:dataTable>
```

None of those buttons fire their's method in backing bean. But if I move then outside of dataTable, they work just fine.

Here's the back bean, running on WildFly 8 with Deltaspike:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class RecController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<EmpresaRecolheInss> empresas = new ArrayList<>();

@Inject
private BaseDAO dao;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    congeneres = dao.listar(Congenere.class);
    empresas.add(new EmpresaRecolheInss());
}

public void salvar(){
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Salvo", null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

public void addItem(){
    empresas.add(new EmpresaRecolheInss());
}

public void removeItem(Empresa eri){
    empresas.remove(eri);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug of the BootsFaces 0.9.1 datatable I've repaired last weekend. Also see https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/486. The bug will be solved with BootsFaces 1.0. Until then, you can use the BootsFaces-1.0.0 developer snapshot on Maven Central as long as you're aware it's not meant to be used in production. See https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369 on how to get the "sneak preview" version.